# Using group by and joins in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables on a PostgreSQL database, contracts and payments. One contract has multiple payments done.

I'm having the two following models:

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var contracts = sequelize.define('contracts', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        contracts.hasMany(models.payments, {
          foreignKey: 'contract_id'
        });
      }
    }
  });


  return contracts;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var payments = sequelize.define('payments', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    contract_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    payment_amount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        payments.belongsTo(models.contracts, {
          foreignKey: 'contract_id'
        });
      }
    }
  });


  return payments;
};
```

I would like to sum all the payments made for every contract, and used this function:

```
models.contracts.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id'
    ],
    include: [
    {
        model: models.payments,
        attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn('sum', models.sequelize.col('payments.payment_amount')), 'total_cost']]
    }
    ],
    group: ['contracts.id']
})
```

But it generates the following query:

```
SELECT "contracts"."id", "payments"."id" AS "payments.id", sum("payments"."payment_amount") AS "payments.total_cost" 
FROM "contracts" AS "contracts" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "payments" AS "payments" ON "contracts"."id" = "payments"."contract_id" GROUP BY "contracts"."id";
```

I do not ask to select payments.id, because I would have to include it in my aggregation or group by functions, as said in the error I have:

> Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: error: column "payments.id"
>   must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Am I missing something here ? I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700004/how-can-i-do-a-group-by-across-3-tables-with-sequelize) but even there I don't understand how the SQL request can be valid.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This issue has been fixed on Sequelize 3.0.1, the primary key of the included models must be excluded with

```
attributes: []
```

and the aggregation must be done on the main model (infos in [this github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3441)).

Thus for my use case, the code is the following

```
models.contracts.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', [models.sequelize.fn('sum', models.sequelize.col('payments.payment_amount')), 'total_cost']],
    include: [
    {
        model: models.payments,
        attributes: []
    }
    ],
    group: ['contracts.id']
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
group: ['contracts.id', 'payments.id']
```

Comment: Thanks but if I group by 'payments.id' I won't be able to sum the payments.payment_amount.

Comment: How bout `attributes: ['payment_amount', [models.sequelize.fn('sum', models.sequelize.col('payments.payment_amount')), 'total_cost']]`. Basically sequelize will select the id if "nothing" is selected. If that works I will update my answer. Hope it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, always the same error: `Possibly unhandled SequelizeDatabaseError: column "payments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 3):

Can you write your function as

```
models.contracts.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'models.contracts.id'
    ],
    include: [
    {
        model: models.payments,
        attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn('sum', models.sequelize.col('payments.payment_amount')), 'total_cost']]
    }
    ],
    group: ['contracts.id']
})
```

Comment: Did you mean 'contracts.id' instead of 'models.contracts.id' ? Anyway the first one gives me the same error and the second one throws another SQL error (missing FROM clause).

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue that you might want to be selecting from `payments` and joining `contracts` rather than the other way around?