# Node.js - How to get sum and avg of column using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sum, sequelize.js, average

In node.js, I want to get sum of one column which has `STRING` dataType and value is like `"367793582429824"`.

I just tried like as mentioned below but its throwing an error like `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "assetamount" does not exist`

```
[
 sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("assetAmount")), "totalAssetAmount",
],
```

Model is,

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const items = sequelize.define("Items", {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  assetAmount: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
 });
};
```

Also I want to calculate an average of this column, how can I get SUM and AVG of this column?

Comment: can you share ur model schema in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dataType is in STRING and `SUM` or `AVG` is a numeric function, first you need to cast the column into integer.

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let resp = await model.Item.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Sequelize.fn("SUM", Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col("assetAmount"), 'integer')), "totalAssetAmount"], 
    [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('assetAmount'), 'integer')), 'avgAssetAmount']
  ]
});
```

** Note that if you have non-numeric data in the column, this SQL will fail.
For example, if you have 1 row with `assetAmount = 'hello'`, then this SQL will raise an exception

Some mitigation ideas:

- Filter out all non-numeric rows with `where` option.
- Use [validate](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/validations-and-constraints.html) to enforce having all numeric data in the column
- Modify the DB's schema to numeric column

Comment: Getting `SequelizeDatabaseError: integer out of range`

Comment: That means your value is out of what integer can hold (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647).  Try `'bigint'` instead of `'integer'` and see.

Answer (score 0):

i just created same shema in squelize as urs and run query to get sum and average u can use this code its working at my end..

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Item = sequelize.define(
        "Item",
        {
            assetAmount: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            freezeTableName: true,
        }
    );
    return Item;
};
```

db data

[image]

here is my query for sum and avg

```js
        let resp = await model.Item.findAll({
            attributes: [[
                model.sequelize.fn("sum", model.sequelize.col("assetAmount")), "totalAssetAmount",
            ], [model.sequelize.fn('AVG', model.sequelize.col('assetAmount')), 'avgRating']]
        });
console.log(resp)
```

Here is Response as u required

```
[
    {
        "totalAssetAmount": 1469134,
        "avgRating": 734567
    }
]
```

Comment: I am getting `SequelizeDatabaseError: function sum(character varying) does not exist`

Comment: it means Store numbers in a numeric field, an integer, decimal or whatever. But not in a text/varchar field.

Comment: I have fixed this issue, but now I am getting `SequelizeDatabaseError: column "Item.assetAmount" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638509/10079978 check this answer